Asymptotic properties of the estimator in IV panel regression
I am studying the rationale behind using the SYS-GMM estimator from Baltagi's book.
Consider the following Data Generating Process (DGP):
\begin{equation}
y_{it} = \rho y_{i,t-1} + \alpha_i + \nu_{it},
\end{equation}
with $ \mathbb{E}(\alpha_i) = 0 $, $ \mathbb{E}(\nu_{it}) = 0 $, and $ \mathbb{E}(\alpha_i \nu_{it}) = 0 $ for $ i = 1, 2, \dots, N $ and $ t = 1, 2, \dots, T $. Finally, assume $ | \rho| <1 $.
Define the composite error term as $ u_{it} = \alpha_i + \nu_{it} $.
Blundell and Bond (1998) focus on the case where $ T = 3 $, and therefore there is only one orthogonality condition given by
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(y_{i1} \Delta \nu_{i3}) = 0,
\end{equation}
which implies that $\rho$ is just-identified. In this case, the first-stage IV regression is obtained by regressing $ \Delta y_{i2} $ on $ y_{i1} $. This regression can be derived from the first equation evaluated at $ t = 2 $ by subtracting $ y_{i1} $ from both sides:
\begin{equation}
\Delta y_{i2} = (\rho - 1)y_{i1} + \alpha_i + \nu_{i2}.
\end{equation}
Since $ \mathbb{E}(y_{i1} \alpha_i) > 0 $, $(\rho - 1)$ will be biased upwards, and we have:
\begin{equation}
\text{plim}(\hat{\rho} - 1) = (\rho - 1) \frac{c}{c + \left(\frac{\sigma_{\alpha}^2}{\sigma_u^2}\right)},
\end{equation}
where $c = \frac{1-\rho}{1+\rho}$ is a constant, and $ \frac{\sigma_{\alpha}^2}{\sigma_u^2} $ is the ratio of the variances.
However, when I attempt to derive the plim above, I get a different result, specifically:
\begin{equation}
\text{plim}(\hat{\rho} -1) = (\rho -1) + \frac{ \text{Cov}(y_{i1}, \Delta y_{i2} ) }{ \text{Var}(y_{i1}) }.
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\text{Cov}(y_{i1}, \Delta y_{i2}) = \text{Cov}(y_{i1}, (\rho - 1)y_{i1} + \alpha_i + \nu_{i2}) = (\rho - 1) \text{Var}(y_{i1}) + \text{Cov}(\alpha_i, y_{i1}) + \text{Cov}(\nu_{i2}, y_{i1})
\end{equation}
First, since $y_{i1}$ follows a stationary AR(1) process, it can be rewritten as:
\begin{equation}
y_{i1} = \frac{\alpha_i}{1 - \rho} + \frac{\nu_{i1}}{1 - \rho}.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{Var}(y_{i1}) = \frac{ \sigma^{2}_{\alpha} +  \sigma^{2}_{\nu} }{ (1 - \rho)^2 }
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\text{Cov}(\alpha_i, y_{i1}) = \frac{\sigma^{2}_{\alpha}}{1-\rho}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\text{Cov}(\nu_{i2}, y_{i1})=0
\end{equation}
Combining these results, I find:
\begin{equation}
\text{plim}(\hat{\rho} -1) = (\rho -1) \left( 2 - \frac{\sigma^{2}_{\alpha}}{\sigma^{2}_{u}} \right),
\end{equation}
where $\sigma^{2}_{u} = \sigma^{2}_{\alpha} + \sigma^{2}_{\nu}$.
What am I doing wrong in my derivation?
